# Matlab: Assigning same value to (different) fields in the same position of a struct array

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, field, variable-assignment

Suppose I have a `1x10` struct `my_struct` with two fields: `fieldA` and `fieldB`.

How should I assign a scalar number (or any other entity) on a specific position for all fields in a more direct form?

In other words, is there a way to do this:

```
my_struct(5).fieldA = pi;
my_struct(5).fieldB = pi;
```

In a way like this: `my_struct(5).* = pi` or `my_struct(5) = deal(pi)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `fieldnames` and `cell2struct` to programmatically build up a struct with the same value in all fields, and then do full-struct assignment.

```
function out = setAllFields(s, value)
%SETALLFIELDS Build a scalar struct from template, replacing all field values
% Where s is your template struct, and value is the value desired in all fields
out = cell2struct(repmat({value}, [numel(fieldnames(s)) 1]), fieldnames(s));
```

With that function defined, you can do the assignment like this, using single or multiple target indexes.

```
my_struct(5) = setAllFields(my_struct, pi);
my_struct([2 4:6]) = setAllFields(my_struct, 'foo');
```